# window title truncated on citrix client through autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, titlebar, citrix

Is there any way to change a Citrix client to not truncate the window title bar if it is over so many characters?  It actually doesn't truncate it on the graphic representation of the title bar, but when using AutoHotKey, it is truncated.

For instance, the title bar in the window shows:
Inventory Management - View/Edit Purchase Orders   [001:INV:PORDR:001:A00208]

The AutoHotKey line associated with that Citrix window shows:
Inventory Management - View/Edit Purchase Orders   [001:INV:PO - \Remote

When viewing the application on the server instead of through Citrix, the AutoHotKey line is not truncated.

Comment: What code are you using to retrieve the Window title? Does it show the full title in Window Spy?

Comment: We are trying to set up our accounting software (installed on a Citrix machine) to use Treeno, which is a document repository that allows you to link documents.  The Treeno guys say they use AutoHotKey.  I don't know about Window Spy...I'll have to look into that.

Comment: AutoHotKey has something called AutoIT3 Window Spy.  It shows this:

Comment: >>>>>>>>>>( Window Title & Class )<<<<<<<<<<<  
Inventory Management - View/Edit Purchase Orders   [001:INV:PO - \\Remote  
ahk_class Transparent Windows Client  
  
>>>>>>>>>>>>( Mouse Position )<<<<<<<<<<<<<  
On Screen: 1002, 89  (less often used)  
In Active Window: 958, 11  
  
>>>>>>>>>( Now Under Mouse Cursor )<<<<<<<<  
  
Color: 0xDEEBEF  (Blue=DE Green=EB Red=EF)

Comment: >>>>>>>>>>( Active Window Position )<<<<<<<<<<  
left: 44     top: 78     width: 807     height: 255  
  
>>>>>>>>>>>( Status Bar Text )<<<<<<<<<<  
  
>>>>>>>>>>>( Visible Window Text )<<<<<<<<<<<  
  
>>>>>>>>>>>( Hidden Window Text )<<<<<<<<<<<  
  
>>>>( TitleMatchMode=slow Visible Text )<<<<  
  
>>>>( TitleMatchMode=slow Hidden Text )<<<<

Comment: @ElliotDeNolf I'm sorry for the posting errors.  This is my first post to stackoverflow.  Suffice it to say, the Window Spy interface shows the same thing, except it has \\Remote instead of \Remote like I got when I just used AutoHotKey

Comment: If it is not showing the full title in Window Spy, there is not much AHK can do as far as I know.

Comment: You could investigate, what other info the window exposes. Have a look the **window text** categories shown by the window spy.

Comment: Is there any setting on the Citrix client that would expose more?  It doesn't truncate the title when it isn't going through Citrix.